# How to draw an SVG onclick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, onclick

I have a React component that shows the coordinates of onclick event and and imported SVG file.

How can be added the SVG image where onclick is done and to that specific coordinate?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import mySVG from './assets/activeTab.svg';
import './Coordinates.css';

export default class Coordinates extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0};
  }

  _onMouseMove(e) {
    this.setState({ x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY });
  }

  render() {
    const { x, y } = this.state;
    let { points } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <h1>
          Mouse coordinates: {x} {y}
        </h1>
        <img src={mySVG} alt='' />
        <div
          className='my-content'
          onClick={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)}
        ></div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just position the image with css using the values in state.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import mySVG from "./activeTab.svg";

export default class Coordinates extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0 };
  }

  _onMouseMove(e) {
    e.persist();
    this.setState({ x: e.nativeEvent.layerX, y: e.nativeEvent.layerY });
  }

  render() {
    const { x, y } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <h1>
          Mouse coordinates: {x} {y}
        </h1>

        <div
          style={{ height: 400, background: "peachpuff", position: "relative" }}
          onClick={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)}
        >
          <img
            style={{
              position: "absolute",
              top: this.state.y,
              left: this.state.x,
              width: 60,
              height: 60
            }}
            src={mySVG}
            alt=""
          />
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit zen-northcutt-cex0n]

If you want to keep adding a new instance of the image on every click, you could track the history of each click within state like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import mySVG from "./activeTab.svg";

export default class Coordinates extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { x: 0, y: 0, history: [] };
  }

  _onMouseMove(e) {
    e.persist();
    const latest = { x: e.nativeEvent.layerX, y: e.nativeEvent.layerY };
    this.setState({
      ...latest,
      history: [...this.state.history, latest]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { x, y, history } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <h1>
          Mouse coordinates: {x} {y}
        </h1>

        <div
          style={{ height: 400, background: "peachpuff", position: "relative" }}
          onClick={this._onMouseMove.bind(this)}
        >
          {history.map((item) => {
            return (
              <img
                style={{
                  position: "absolute",
                  top: item.y,
                  left: item.x,
                  width: 60,
                  height: 60
                }}
                src={mySVG}
                alt=""
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit pensive-bush-m6nd3]

Note: the above is likely to run into performance issues at a certain point. If your intention is to *paint* many instances of these images, you might want to consider looking into [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API).

Comment: it looks great but is it possible to keep the previous drawn images? now it creates a new one and removes the previous one at each step